# How to add fragment during runtime in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I am trying to write a program that can display one fragment when the device is in portrait mode and another when it is in landscape mode. I have encountered some problems which makes the code not to work:

I used the getWidth() and getHeight () to get the portrait and landscape mode, but the functions are struck out as deprecated in 4.3 what other function can I use to do this?

I used the replace() function to display the fragment I want, but it’s been struck out as an error

The complete code is below. You will find that I have indicated where the errors are using arrows and comments, so you would know exactly where the problem is in my code. Please take a look at my code and help me fix it.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    //---get the current display info---
    WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    if (d.getWidth() > d.getHeight())//<----------these two functions get struck out as //an error
    {
    //---landscape mode---
        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        // android.R.id.content refers to the content
        // view of the activity
        fragmentTransaction.replace( //<------this replace() function is seen as an //error
                android.R.id.content, fragment1);
        }
    else
    {
    //---portrait mode---
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(//<------this replace() function is also seen as an //error
            android.R.id.content, fragment2);

    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
**/

}
```

Comment: Use the same `Fragment` for both orientations but simply have two different layout files? Or are the two `Fragments` supposed to do completely different things?

Comment: Can you paste in your LogCat so that we can see the error, or is this a compiler error?  BTW:  you actually have two questions.  I have an answer for your first, but not on your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a pattern like this in your onCreate.  It is much cleaner, plus it uses the proper getSupportFragmentManager() instead of the inherited, and limited, `getFragmentManager()`:

```
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

            Fragment1 placeholder = new Fragment1();
            placeholder.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, placeholder).commit();
        } else
        {
            Fragment2 placeholder = new Fragment2();
            placeholder.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, placeholder).commit();
        }
```

Comment: You only need the 'support' `FragmentManager` if you're using the support libraries.

Comment: He is extending `ActionBarActivity`.  So, I think that he is using the support library.  I get compile errors when trying to `.add` or `.replace` an extended Fragment (ie Fragment1, or Fragment2); says it must have a type `Fragment` for ActionBarActivity. I believe these are the errors he is referring to.  But, there could be something else causing this in my limited code example that I am missing. I'll submit to, someone with more experience, but my example won't let me do it.

Comment: Sorry - you have a valid point. I hadn't spotted he is extending `ActionBarActivity`. You're right - I suspect there are conflicting imports which are causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check actual screen orientation by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //load landscape fragment
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //load portrait fragment
    }
}
```

Same can be done `onCreate()`. Your configuration can be recalled with

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

Take a look [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) also, because you might need to edit your manifest file a little bit. For the activity to handle orientation changes, you need to set:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two `Activity` layouts but give them exactly the same name (example activity_main.xml).

Put one in your res/layout-port directory...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container-port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Put the other in res/layout-land directory...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container-land"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the `FrameLayouts` have different resource ids (`@+id/container-port` and `@+id/container-land`).

In your `MainActivity`, simply use code as follows...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    FrameLayout container;
    boolean isPortrait = true

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container-port);
        if (container == null) {
            isPortrait = false;
            container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container-land);
        }

        ...

     }
}
```

Android will automatically inflate the relevant layout based on the orientation of the device. There's no need to get width / height or even to check the orientation directly. This is done implicitly by  trying to use `findViewById(...)` and by setting the boolean accordingly based on whether or not the container is `null`. From then on, you can use the `isPortrait` boolean to dictate how your code works.

Also, N8sBug is correct about using `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using the support libraries.